# modx revo генерация title

Tags: modx, revo

Помогите, пожалуйста!
Сайт на Modx Revo.
В поле расширенный заголовок:

```
Услуги патентных поверенных в [$город]
```

вызывается чанк, значение которого меняется в зависимости от поддомена

Текст в заголовок генерируется следующим образом:

```
<title>[*longtitle]</title>
```

в итоге следующий мусор

```
Услуги патентных поверенных в <!----><!--Казани-->
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста как генерировать заголовок без этого мусора?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте вставить сам чанк где-нибудь на страницу что выводит? или приведите код чанка

Comment: спасибо, уже разобралась, оказывается - там помимо города еще и выводилась закомментированная строка )